How i can resolve this problem with assigning roles
I cannot asign user to role in my web.api
I seeded my roles in the db in my Program.cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
 {
     var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
     var roles = new[] { "Admin", "User" };

     foreach (var role in roles)
     {
         if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
         {
             await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
         }
     }
 }

AccountController
            var appUser = new User
            {
                Email = request.Email,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, request.Password);
           
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, "User");

AspNetUserRoles
enter image description here
How i can assign user to role?

Have you added AddIdentity and AddEntityFrameworkStores
Following code works fine
Program.cs
builder.Services
      .AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestApp"))
      .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

Adding User and Role
 var roles = new[] { "Admin", "User" };

 foreach (var role in roles)
 {
     if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
     {
         await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
     }
 }

 var appUser = new IdentityUser
 {
     Email = "test@uat.co",
     UserName= "test@uat.co",
 };

 var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, "Password_1");
 await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, "User");

DB Context
public class DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : IdentityDbContext(options)
{
   
}


